# Unit test $window resize method

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, window, karma-jasmine

I have the following code in a simple directive link function which checks for a window resize and calls a function.

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope) {
        angular.element($window).on('resize', function() {
            scope.getSize();
        });

        scope.getSize() = function() {
            return true;
        };
    }
}
```

I'm trying to test on `($window).on('resize')` that `scope.getSize()` is called.

In my tests I compile my directive like so:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile, _$window_) {
    $window = _$window_;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = angular.element('<div data-watch-resize></div>');
    element = $compile(element)($scope);
    $scope.$digest();
}));
```

I then spy on the resize function of window, and expect the function to have been called

```
spyOn($window, 'resize');
$window.innerWidth = 1026;
$scope.$digest();
expect(element.scope().getSize()).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

however i get the following error

`Error: resize() method does not exist`

I'm not really sure why it doesn't exist, is there something obvious I am doing wrong?

Comment: u probably need to create a fake function for resize method as it's a dom method.

Comment: i've tried doing `spyOn($window, 'resize').and.callFake(function() {
 // do something });` but that doesn't appear to work either

Comment: maybe try changing $window.innerWidth twice so there is actually a resizing action?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if anyone gets stuck on something similar:

```
it('should expect scope.getSize() to have been called on window resize', function () {
    spyOn(element.isolateScope(), 'getSize');
    $window.innerWidth = 1026;
    angular.element($window).triggerHandler('resize');
    $scope.$digest();
    expect(element.isolateScope().getSize).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a nearly identical directive and test configured, but I receive this error: `could not find an object to spy upon for getSize()` Did you encounter that at all?

Comment: @isherwood would suggest what you are calling doesn't exist? the equivalent above would be element.isolateScope() not being there

Comment: I never did get the spy to work, but I got around it by removing the spy and simply checking for the class changes I was expecting after compilation.